# Why did Ramdha ask "Which sister are you?"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

In Star Trek: Picard, when Soji meets Ramdha in the mess hall, Ramdha asks "Which sister are you?".

But I don't remember there being anything about twin sisters in the Admonition.

Was there? Or is Ramdha referring to something else?

Comment: I don't remember anything about it in what we see of the Admonition. However, at the start of the series the Zhat Vash seemingly already knew there were (at least) two sisters. It's unclear where that information came from, but since Picard had a painting with the likeness of Dahj/Soji which predates the series by 30 years, perhaps other clues to the existence of the sisters existed and was pieced together by the Zhat Vash. Especially given the access to information Commodore Oh's position granted.

Comment: But we don't really know what Ramdha really saw, do we? All we know was the INTERPRETATION given by the bio-Androids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer I can proffer is that Narissa or Narek told her at some point. There's some circumstantial evidence to support this

## Spoilers ahead

- [Ramdha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ramdha) is Narek and Narissa's aunt. She raised them and both of them seem to revere her as their mother, despite her poor mental condition
- Ramdha was Zhat Vash, as we see both her and Narissa experience the [Admonition](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Admonition). I could easily see Narissa or Narek telling an apparently autistic Ramdha about what they were doing with the Zhat Vash, hoping it would help her return to her old self.
- Narissa looks in on the unconscious Ramdha before departing the cube. Narissa is apparently disappointed that Ramdha has not regained consciousness. This implies Narissa looked in on her from time to time.